.desktop shortcut doesnt launch the application
I downloaded the Grayjay app for Linux. Running it from it's folder via double click works as expected. However, when I create a shortcut it will not launch.
See Screenshot.
The shortcut is set to allow launching.
What am I missing?
.desktop location:
/home/roger/.local/share/applications
Ubuntu 24.04


Is the /home/roger/Grayjay folder in your system path?

Please edit your question and add information which release and flavor of Ubuntu you are using. Please also add to your post the absolute path where the .desktop file you created is stored.

.desktop location:
/home/roger/.local/share/applications
Ubuntu 24.04
Is the folder in my system path? What do you mean?

Run ls -l <path-to-desktop-file> let see the permissions

Welcome to ASK. Does the Icon appear in the 'ShowApps' menu (bottom left)? If so what happens with a single click? Nothing? If so examine the Exec line carefully for errors. If its correct then try to run it with a known working target such as the following: - 'Exec=/bin/gnome-terminal -e "thunderbird"'

@david Yes, it shows under Show Apps. Single click does nothing. The exec line is correct (copy paste).

Setup gnome-terminal with a profile set to 'hold the terminal open' To do this run 'gnome-terminal --preferences' create a profile and set the command to 'hold the terminal open' Then set this to default. Next change the .desktop file with the Exec as follows 'Exec=gnome-terminal -e "[path-to-your-application]"' and then run the app from the icon. It will run a gnome-terminal and then attempt to run your application. After which the terminal will remain open which may contain error messages. After this remove the profile.

@david there indeed seems to be an error, but I cant possibly fathom what it means.
"CEF:CEF directory '/home/roger/cef'.
CEF:Working directory '/home/roger/cef'.
CEF:CEF exe path '/home/roger/cef/dotcefnative'.
CEF:File not found at native path '/home/roger/cef/dotcefnative'.
Keyring:Falling back to file keyring
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Native executable not found.
at DotCef.DotCefProcess.Start(String args)
at Grayjay.Desktop.Program.Main(String[] args)
at Grayjay.Desktop.Program.(String[] args)
"
All the shortcut should do is launch the program.

I think it is reporting that '/home/roger/cef/dotcefnative. cannot be found. What does 'whereis dotcefnative' report? I think it looks in $PATH for the path.  https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/exec-variables.html

@david well, that folder/program is inside of the grayjay folder: /home/roger/Desktop/Grayjay.Desktop-linux-x64-v2/cef - I have no idea why a shortcut causes the Grayjay application to fail so miserably. This should be a simple thing to do, and is in all major operating systems... you make a shortcut to run the application without having to open it's directory all the time. What could be the problem?

Try adding the path  of cef you  PATH. So change the Exec to the following: - 'Exec=gnome-terminal -e "env PATH=/home/roger/Desktop/Grayjay.Desktop-linux-x64-v2/cef:$PATH [path-to-your-application]"' (.desktop files can be somewhat fussy. I have not tried this so the syntax might be wrong.)

@david nope, doesnt work. thanks for your efforts, but it looks like that creating a shortcut in Ubuntu (or linux?) is highly flawed and requires a complete overhaul.

Bug report opened here: https://github.com/futo-org/Grayjay.Desktop/issues/209
